# Fixed left navigation + remaining space

Tags: css, navigation, positioning, fixed, sidebar

I'm trying to achieve the following with CSS:
I want a **fixed sidebar** with navigation, so that when you scroll down, the sidebar stays in it's place. The remaining space on the right should be filled up with my content, as if it were the body at 100%.

However, my problem is that the right part takes exactly 300px more space on the right, resulting in a horizontal scroll bar.

I can't fid a solution on my own, can anybody help me? Thanks a lot! :)

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/ALGpP/4/

```
nav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 300px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index:99;
}

#wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left:300px;
}
```

Comment: it always helps if you include a working example in http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: You mean [like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/cuplizian/k72GX/2/)
The different is the `.side` isn't `fixed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Do you mean something like this?**](http://jsfiddle.net/ALGpP/2/)

I gave the `#wrapper` element some new CSS properties:

```
  height: 1200px;
  background-color: red;
```

- The `height: 1200px` is in this case just for testing, to make the page longer.
- The `background-color: red` is also just for testing to make it more visible.

Your `nav` element i have given the following css properties:

```
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: green;
```

- The `height: 100%` is used to make the element fill the page in the height
- The `width: 20%` is used to make it `20%` width.
- The `position: fixed`is to make the element stick to a certain point at the page.
- The `background-color` is used for testing, so you can see better what you're doing.

---

Also, i reccomend using a CSS reset. This is a really simple one im using in the fiddle:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

It basicly selects all elements and gives it a `margin` and `padding` of `0`.

---

If you want the `nav` element to be `300px` wide, use **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ALGpP/3/)**.

---

**Fix for the content that wasnt showing**

Add the following properties to your `#wrapper` element:

```
width: calc(100% - 300px);
float: right;
```

So it looks like this:

```
#wrapper {
    width: calc(100% - 300px);
    height: 1200px;
    background-color: red;
    float: right;
}
```

**[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/ALGpP/5/)**

Comment: Percentage width would solve the problem, but I want a fixed with. Also, the content isn't visible in your fiddle :(

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/ALGpP/3/ it uses `px` as width. I know, fixing that now.

Comment: That does it, thanks a lot! Also, thanks for introducing me to calc(), I had never heard of it. Very interesting!